# Extract Data from CSV

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I have a file which consists of nearly 10000 rows of data. I want to extract some data corresponding to some element. For example

I want to extract values of xErr for say, `x>22.1 and x<22.3`.

The data are in a CSV file.

How can I do this?

I have tried using `np.where()` but I'm unsuccessful.

Comment: I have tried t['xErr'][np.where(t['x']>22.1 and np.where(t['x']<22.3)] but this does not work. t is the table containing all the data. Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use pandas and it will be very simple. Just Google how to read a CSV with pandas and then look for examples of how to filter your data frame.

There are a lot of other posts on here that cover this problem.